# If $\log(x^2+2ax)=\log(4x-4a-13)$ has only one solution, find the exhaustive set of values of $a$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

> > If $\log(x^2+2ax)=\log(4x-4a-13)$ has only one solution, then what is the exhaustive set of values of $a$ ?

This question was asked at [Equation $\log(x^2+2ax)=\log(4x-4a-13)$ has only one solution; then exhaustive set of values of $a$ is](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1644515/equation-logx22ax-log4x-4a-13-has-only-one-solution-then-exhaustive-s), but the answers there don't match my book's given answer $$\left(-{13}4,-\frac{13}{12}\right) \cup [-1].$$

**My Approach:**

For $\log(4x-4a-13)$ to be valid, $4x-4a-13>0,$ i.e., $x>\frac{4a+13}{4}.$

For $\log(x^2+2ax)$ to be valid, $x^2+2ax>0,$ i.e., $x(x+2a)>0;$ here we have two cases

- **case 1** $a>0$

  $\implies$ $x\in(-\infty,-2a)\cup (0,\infty)$
- **case 2** $a<0$

  $\implies$ $x\in(-\infty,0)\cup (2a,\infty).$

For one solution, $x^2+2ax=4x-4a-13$ and its discriminant equals $0.$ So, I got $a=-1$ and $a=9.$ For $a=9,$ I got $x=-7$ which not a valid solution because $\log(x^2+2ax)$ will be invalid.

But how to arrive at the other part of the given solution?

Comment: The given answer is not correct since $a=-\frac{13}{4}$ and $a=-\frac{13}{12}$ have to be included.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We want to find $a$ such that there is only one $x$ satisfying
$$x^2+2ax=4x-4a-13\tag1$$
$$x^2+2ax\gt 0\tag2$$
$$4x-4a-13\gt 0\tag3$$

The discriminant of $x^2+(2a-4)x+4a+13=0$ has to be non-negative, so it is necessary that $a\in (-\infty,-1]\cup [9,\infty)$.

- $a=-1$ is sufficient since $x=3$ is the only solution.
- $a=9$ is not sufficient since the equation has no solutions.
- For $a\in (-\infty,-1)\cup (9,\infty)$, let $p,q\ (p\lt q)$ be the solutions of $(1)$ where $$p=2-a-\sqrt{(a+1)(a-9)},\quad q=2-a+\sqrt{(a+1)(a-9)}$$ Then, one can see that
  $$\begin{align}&\text{$p$ satisfies $(2)$ and $(3)$}
  \\\\&\iff 4\bigg(2-a-\sqrt{(a+1)(a-9)}\bigg)-4a-13\gt 0
  \\\\&\iff 4\sqrt{(a+1)(a-9)}\lt -8a-5
  \\\\&\iff -8a-5\gt 0\quad \text{and}\quad  16(a+1)(a-9)\lt (-8a-5)^2
  \\\\&\iff a\lt -\frac{13}{4}\quad \text{or}\quad -\frac{13}{12}\lt a\lt -1\tag4\end{align}$$
  and that
  $$\begin{align}&\text{$q$ satisfies $(2)$ and $(3)$}
  \\\\&\iff 4\bigg(2-a+\sqrt{(a+1)(a-9)}\bigg)-4a-13\gt 0
  \\\\&\iff 4\sqrt{(a+1)(a-9)}\gt 8a+5
  \\\\&\iff 8a+5\leqslant 0\quad \text{or}\quad \bigg(8a+5\gt 0\quad \text{and}\quad 16(a+1)(a-9)\gt (8a+5)^2\bigg)
  \\\\&\iff a\lt -1\tag5\end{align}$$What we want is $a$ such that only one of $(4)(5)$ is satisfied. So, $a\in [-\frac{13}{4},-\frac{13}{12}]$.

Therefore, the answer is
$$\color{red}{a\in\bigg[-\frac{13}{4},-\frac{13}{12}\bigg]\cup [-1]}$$

Comment: @ryang : Note that $p,q$ are the solutions of $(1)$. So, both $p^2+2ap=4p-4a-13$ and $q^2+2aq=4q-4a-13$ hold.

Comment: @ryang : I know. Since we have $p^2+2ap=4p-4a-13$, $4p-4a-13\gt 0$ is equivalent to $p^2+2ap\gt 0$. Also, since $q^2+2aq=4q-4a-13$, $4q-4a-13\gt 0$ is equivalent to $q^2+2aq\gt 0$.

Comment: Oh yes, of course, hehe. +1.

Comment: A very well written answer!

Answer (score 2):

> > If $$\log(x^2+2ax)=\log(4x-4a-13)$$ has only one solution, then what is the exhaustive set of values of $a$ ?

\begin{align}&\log(x^2+2ax)=\log(4x-4a-13)
\\\iff&x^2+(2a-4)x+(4a+13)=0\quad\text{and}\quad 4x-4a-13>0
\\\iff&x=2-a\pm\sqrt{(a+1)(a-9)}\quad\text{and}\quad x>a+\frac{13}4.\tag1\end{align}

We want precisely the union of **the cases in which $(1)$ has exactly one solution**:

- $a=-1\quad$ and $\quad2-a\pm0>a+\dfrac{13}4$

  $\iff a=-1$
- $a=9\quad$ and $\quad2-a\pm0>a+\dfrac{13}4$

  $\iff a\in\emptyset$
- $2-a-\sqrt{(a+1)(a-9)}\le a+\dfrac{13}4\quad$ and $\quad2-a+\sqrt{(a+1)(a-9)}>a+\dfrac{13}4$

  $\iff -\frac{13}4\le a\le -\frac{13}{12}\quad$ (I'm just [using Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/zkdfhzww4o) here, as the algebra is distracting.)

Thus, the required set is $$\left[-\frac{13}4,-\frac{13}{12}\right]\cup\{-1\}.$$ (As pointed out by mathlove, your book's given solution is not quite correct.)

---

**Addendum**

Here's an analogous exercise that—unless solved geometrically—requires the same solution structure:

> A triangle $PQR$ is such that $PQ = 2, QR = p$ and $\measuredangle RPQ = 30^\circ.$
> For which values of p is $PR$ uniquely determined?

Let $PR=q.\:$ By the Cosine Rule, $$p^2=q^2+2^2-2(2)(q)\cos30^\circ\\
q^2-2\sqrt3q+(4-p^2)=0\\
q=\sqrt3\pm\sqrt{p^2-1}$$ **$q$ is uniquely-determined iff** either

- $p^2-1=0\;$ (zero discriminant)

or

- $p^2-1>0$ and $\sqrt{p^2-1}\geq\sqrt3$

  (positive discriminant but only one positive solution),

i.e., $$p\in\{1\}\cup[2,\infty).$$

Answer (score 0):

The reason you didn't get the other part of the solution set is that you assumed the discriminant of $x^2+2ax=4x-4a-13$ must be zero for a unique solution. This is certainly one of the cases where there is one solution, but not the only case. The quadratic can have two roots, if one of the two roots is invalid because of the domain of $\log(x)$, even in this case, the equation will have only one solution.
$$ a^2-8a-9 >0 $$
$$ \implies a \in (-\infty,-1) \cup(9, \infty)$$
Now, for these values of $a$, check for the cases where **exactly** one of $\log(x^2+2ax)$ and $\log(4x-4a-13)$ is undefined, i.e. $x^2+2ax \le 0$ or $4x-4a-13 \le 0$

Comment: I still don't understand why you did $x^2+2ax\leq 0$ and $4x-4a-13\leq 0$

Comment: @mathophile I did that because $\log(x)$ is not defined for $x \le 0$. Either $\log(x^2+2ax)$ is not defined (i.e. $x^2+2ax \le 0$) or $\log(4x-4a-13)$ is not defined (i.e. $4x-4a-13 \le 0$)

Comment: @AnkitSaha Your argument is flawed: remember, if $\log(x^2+2ax)$ is undefined, then so is $\log(4x-4a-13),$ since they are set as equal.

Comment: @ryang I perhaps didn't word my argument very clearly. What I meant is that even if the quadratic equation $x^2+2ax=4x-4a-13$ has two two distinct roots, say $\alpha$ and $\beta$ and if $\alpha^2 + 2a\alpha > 0$ but $\beta^2 + 2a\beta < 0$ then the equation $\log(x^2+2ax) = \log(4x-4a-13)$ will still have exactly one solution, namely $\alpha$ because it is not defined at $\beta$. So both roots of the quadratic equation do not have to be equal for the logarithmic equation to have a unique solution.