# Given $2^x k+2^{-x}=3$, find all values of $k$ such that the equation has exactly one solution.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

This was asked to me by a friend after he took a test at school. He treated the expression like a quadratic and used the discriminant to find $k=\frac94$. Later, he tried putting in random values for $k$, and saw that any number less than or equal would also have only solution. Can anyone explain this?`

Comment: If $t=2^{x}$, then we can rewrite the equation as: $kt^2-3t+1=0$. Note that $t>0$, so we want all those values of $k$ for which the parabola $y=kt^2-3t+1$ intersects the $x-$axis at exactly one **positive** point. So, the roots must be real AND of opposite signs.

Comment: I meant the $t-$axis, not the $x-$axis.

Comment: @AnuragA We could also have the roots be a double root, which is the $k = 9/4$ case that OP mentioned.  Your case leads to $ k \leq 0$ (which is the correct answer to the question).

Comment: [If $\log(x^2+2kx)=\log(4x-4k-13)$ has exactly one solution, find all the possible values of $k$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4354089/21813)

Comment: @AnuragA, how can we know that y intersects x-axis in exactly one point (repeated root?)?

Answer (score 0):

The quadratic method is intuitive way to solve this question, and is precisely explained by the comments above. However, it does not give a descriptive and conceptual idea behind why certain values were chosen for $k$.

Let us analyse the function $f(x) = k \cdot 2^x + 2^{-x}$. Now, we are trying to find values of $k$ such there is only $1$ value of $x$ satisfying $f(x) = 3$.

As a matter of fact, this is similar as conducting a horizontal line test, to check whether the function behaves as a one-to-one, or many-to-one, but only at value $f(x) = 3$.

Since, $f(x)$ can have **at most** one turning point, we need to find when the turning point is at $(x, f(x) = 3)$ or there is no turning point at all.

We can prove $f(x)$ has at most $1$ minimum, by displaying $f'(x) = 0$ has one solution and $f''(x) > 0$ at the particular turning point. A turning point is indicative of the $f(x)$ repeating itself (many-to-one) for different $x -$ values. Overall, $f(x) = 3$ would follow one of the criteria below;

A) $2$  solutions if $\min{(f(x))} < 3$

B) $1$  solution if $\min{(f(x))} = 3$ or no minimum

C) $0$  solutions if $\min{(f(x))} > 3$

Hence, your solution to the question satisfies condition B. This occurs when;

$$f'(x) = 2^xk\ln{2} - 2^{-x}\ln{2} \\ \quad \\ f'(x) = 0 \Rightarrow x = \dfrac{1}{2}\log_{2}{\dfrac{1}{k}} \\ \quad \\ \therefore \text{$x$ does not exist } \lor f\left(\dfrac{1}{2}\log_{2}{\dfrac{1}{k}}\right) = 2\sqrt{k} = 3 \\ \quad \\ \therefore k \le 0 \lor k = \dfrac{9}{4}$$

Comment: Why do you say that $f(x)$ can have at most one turning point? Thanks.

Comment: @NoChance. As shown above, $x = 0.5\log_{2}{\dfrac{1}{k}}$ is the only solution to $f'(x) = 0$, hence at most one turning point.